# Bluetooth Padlock API?

Tags: bluetooth, locking, rfid, padlock

I'm wondering whether there is an API for a padlock that I can use.
The padlock should be opened via Bluetooth or rfid.

I searched on google but couldn't find the solution for this. I only found padlocks that use an App to open it via Bluetooth. Nothing was mentioned about an API.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. What do you think is the purpose of a public API for a padlock? Are you looking for something that corresponds to the  [Profiles and Services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) of the Bluetooth SIG?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.